# Java Generics

Tags: java, generics

Картина

```
public class Engine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pair<String, Integer> p = new Pair<String, Integer>();

        MethodTest methodTest = new MethodTest();

        methodTest.testGenerics(new MasterCardStandart());
        methodTest.testGenerics(new VisaElectron());
    }

}
```

и

```
public class MethodTest {
    public <T extends IMasterCard &IVisa> void testGenerics(T t) {}
}
```

Ну и

```
public interface IVisa {} public interface IMasterCard {}
```

Я ведь вроде указал, что я хочу, чтобы  принималась имплементация или IVisa, или IMasterCard. Подскажите, как быть в такой ситуации, ругается!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Вы указали, что `T` должен реализовывать **оба** интерфейса - `IVisa` и `IMasterCard`.
- Сама по себе возможность наложения `constraint'a,` в котором тип `T` может реализовывать либо `InterfaceA`, либо `InterfaceB`, обычно не имеет смысла:

> - Любой код, использующий части `InterfaceA`, которые не являются частью `InterfaceB`, не скомпилится в случае подстановки `InterfaceB`.
> - То есть, гипотетический код с `<T extends InterfaceA or InterfaceB>` будет иметь смысл только в случае вызова некоторых **общих** частей `InterfaceA` и `InterfaceB` (под *общими* для простоты можно подразумевать методы с одинаковыми сигнатурами).
> - А это, в свою очередь, означает, что из `InterfaceA` и `InterfaceB` всегда можно выделить `CommonInterfaceForAAndB` и объявить метод как `<T extends CommonInterfaceForAAndB>` с сохранением его поведения.

- Вообще говоря, такая возможность, есть, например, в шаблонах `C++,` если воспользоваться [`SFINAE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) и написать несколько специализаций шаблона для разных типов.

> - Это становится возможным именно благодаря определению ошибок подстановки во время компиляции, что не предусматривается дженериками в `Java`.
> - Естественно, что оправданность такого подхода в реальных сценариях разработки представляется крайне сомнительной.

Answer (score 5):

Хм, не уверен можно ли сделать именно так как ты хочешь, но в данной ситуации я бы ввёл общего предка, например `ICard`, от которого наследуется `IVisa` и `IMasterCard`. А его бы и передавал в качестве параметра дженерику.

Comment: Неплохая мысль, сударь! Но я о другом, интересно если нам предоставляется возможность выбрать подстановочный тип с перечислениями то возможна ли такая элементарная запись =\

Comment: @izaika, на мой взгляд нелогично. Если ты можешь задать несколько типов "через запятую", то возникнет проблема, то что у одного класса один набор методов, у другого другой. Тем самым не понятно, какими методами пользоваться можно, а какими нельзя. Отсюда возникает очевидный ответ - можно пользоваться только множеством пересечений этих методов, что приводит нас опять к наследованию :) Рассуждение абсолютно абстрактно, прошу строго не судить)

А вообще надо бы взять и посмотреть в спецификации что пишут.

Comment: Интересно! А можешь объяснить зачем тогда этот T extends Ia & Ib ...
в чем его фишечка! Ведь можно по идее приводить все к T extends Ia

Comment: В ответе ниже написано, что такая команда говорит, что T должен наследовать оба интерфейса. Т.е. класс, который туда подставляется должен быть объявлен, например так:

    class SomeClass implements IVisa, IMasterCard {
      ...
    }